# How to properly add css selector sequence for border on html form within bootstrap 3.3.7 framework?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, border

I have tried several parent and child element combos and have been unsuccessful at adding a styled border to this form. Below is a condensed version of the html, but it accurately depicts the structure.

```
<div class="container-fluid page-seven" id="pg7">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
            <form id="newUser"  class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="process_form2.php" role="form">
                <div class="row" id="groupcontainer">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="req-Username"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>&nbsp;Username *</label>
                        <input id="req-Username" type="text" name="req-Username" class="form-control" minlength="6" placeholder="Please enter a Username minimum length 6, letters and numbers only *" required="required" data-error="Username is required." value="">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the last attempt at the css code.

```
        #pg7 .row .col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3  #newUser.form-horizontal {
            border: 2px solid magenta;
            padding: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
```

The following is what is shown at the very bottom of the inspector pane in chrome when I have focus on form element:
Without the quotes.

> Blockquote

"html body #pg7 div.row div.col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form#newUser.form-horizontal div#groupcontainer.row div.formgroup"

I can provide a screenshot of the chrome inspector pane if required.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Questions seeking debugging help must include  the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **within the question itself**. [mcve]

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the pointers on the use of images and screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  .form-horizontal {
        border: 2px solid magenta;
        padding: 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Also class selector should be start with (.) dot. and don't give space between combined classes.

Comment: can you please share an example please? it will helpful for me to understand.

Comment: Exactly as you suggested.`code`.form-horizontal {
        border: 2px solid magenta;
        padding: 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

Comment: Turns out that your answer was correct. I had to clear browser data, close browser and reopen browser for changes to css to take effect. I am upvoting your answer.